# How to display comments and it's replies in django templates?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views, django-orm

I want to display comment and it's replies in the template. But there is an issue, every reply may have some other replies. The below snippet is my `Comment` and `CommentReply` model:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(Profile, related_name="c_sender", on_delete=models.CASCADE, unique=False)
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=500, unique=False)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    edited_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.comment

    @property
    def replys(self):
        return CommentReply.objects.filter(comment_id=self)


class CommentReply(models.Model):
    comment_id = models.ForeignKey(Comment, related_name='sender', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    reply_id = models.ForeignKey(Comment, related_name='reply', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

***Updated:***
Also I have a model for WorksComments that every comments that related to Work model saved there.

```
 class WorkComment(models.Model):
     work_id = models.ForeignKey(Work, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='e_exercise', unique=False)
     comment_id = models.ForeignKey(Comment, related_name='e_comment',  unique=False)
```

The below snippet is my view:

```
comments = WorkComment.objects.filter(work_id=work).all()
return render(request, 'work.html', {'comments': comments})
```

My question is how to display comments and it's replies under it, and every reply may have some other replyies that I want to display them too.

Comment: What does your view look like?

Comment: I updated it and added view.

Answer (score 0):

First things first... put this in your bookmarks; https://ccbv.co.uk/

You're going to want a [Detail View](https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.11/django.views.generic.detail/DetailView/) here I suspect in order to display the details of an instance.

Setup URLs...

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from work.views import WorkDetailView

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^(?P<id>[-\d]+)/$', WorkDetailView.as_view(), name='work-detail'),
]
```

And a view;

```
from django.views.generic.detail import DetailView
from django.utils import timezone

from work.models import Work

class WorkDetailView(DetailView):

    model = Work

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(WorkDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['comments'] = WorkComment.objects.filter(work_id=self.object.id).all()
        return context
```

Then a simple view might be `work/work_detail.html`:

```
<h1>{{ object.title }}</h1>
<p>{{ object.content }}</p>
<h2>Comments</h2>
{% for comment in comments %}
    {{ comment }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: it is not a separate page. I want to display comments in a side part of the `work.html` page. my view inherits from View. how can I display them in Class_Based view that inherits from View? thank you

Comment: @msln `DetailView` inherits from `View` as well. The above could render to `work.html` and then just put the comment loop in the markup for the side part. It sounds like my example is what you've already got, but you only posted the line to get the comments & render the response, so I gave a full example.